# Can't insert date because of conversion

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Here is my code:

```
SqlCommand cmda = new SqlCommand(
                        "insert into EnteryItem (ItemName, ImageIndex, DateEntery, Index0, ItemBarcode)"
                        + "Values (@ItemName, GETDATE(), @ImageIndex, @Index0, @ItemBarcode)"
                        , cn);
cn.Open();
cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", "");
//   cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateEntery", now);
cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageIndex", "0");
cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Index0", "");
cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemBarcode", label12.Text);

cmda.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

[image]

I've tried several ways but I get the same

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '28/01/2014' to data type int.

error and sometimes

> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I need to insert date and time, in specific format

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Comment: well can `DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy")` work on `DATETIME`?

Comment: When storing dates, the format is not important - the values you store are.  You identify if you need date, time, date+time (and whether TZ offsets are relevant if you're dealing with time) and store that in your database.  The format that you present to the end user is a concern for your presentation layer.

Comment: now i did changed my datatype from `NVARCHAR (20)` to `DATETIME`, and i still get the same bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare your column names and values

```
ItemName   ImageIndex  DateEntery   Index0   ItemBarcode
@ItemName  GETDATE()   @ImageIndex  @Index0  @ItemBarcode
           ^           ^
```

You'll see the two marked are backwards. It's trying to put a date into an integer column. Correct that and you should be fine

Comment: i did, but still the same bug

Comment: oh my, i think i was blind by not seeing this

Answer (score 6):

Looks like valus for second and third column should are swapped. Should be:

```
insert into EnteryItem (ItemName, ImageIndex, DateEntery, Index0, ItemBarcode)
Values (@ItemName, @ImageIndex, GETDATE(), @Index0, @ItemBarcode)
```

Also note you are not using `@DateEntery` parameter, although you are adding it to the param list.

Comment: i noticed it to, but still the same bug

Comment: @MagedEWilliam, which of the errors you are getting after you have ordered the values properly?

Comment: Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Comment: @MagedEWilliam, can you post the updated code now? Since you have only oone integer column in the table it is strange that the you are still experiencing the same error.